# Is there a way to map 2 dataframes onto each other to produce a rearranged dataframe (with one data frame values acting as the new column names)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have one dataframe of readings that come in a particular arrangement due to the nature of the experiment. I also have another dataframe, that contains information about each point on the dataframe and what each point corresponds to, in terms of what chemical was at that point. Note, there are only a few different chemicals over the dataframe, but they are arranged all over the dataframe.

What I want to do is to create a new, reorganised dataframe, where the columns are the type of chemical. My inital thought would be to compare the data and information dataframes to produce a dictionary, which I could then transform into a new dataframe. I could not figure out how to do this, and might not actually be the best approach either!

I have previously achieved it by manually rearranging the points on the dataframe to match the pattern I want, but I'm not happy with this approach and must be a better way.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hey, please give a sample of your input dataframes, and of your expected output so that we can help ? Thanks

Comment: You probably want to share some example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. And you also probably want some sort of merging. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101